# Upload files to BMC Remedy Mid-Tier

Tags: remedy

I'm a Java developer, absolutely new in BMC Remedy system, but a I have just one fast task to solve.

Our Remedy use Java Applet to upload files from Remedy browser UI to FTP server. I should replace it with Javascript (upload files via http to the server side, which then upload it to FTP server).

In general web application, I can add a servlet, which would receive Multipart file, connect to FTP, upload it and respond with params. Piece of cake.
But is it a right way to solve this problem in Remedy? I've read documentation and it all about some sort of plugins for Remedy Mid-Tier and there is nothing about simple servlets.

What is the right way to solve my task? Any source samples would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if you are doing it via the API, you could just get the record ID, and field ID and do this:

```
//First, we retrieve the form
int[] fieldIds = {1};
String formName = "My:Form:Name";
//Request ID. Field ID = 1. Always 14 chars long.
String requestID = "00000000000001";
Entry entry = arsConnection.getEntry(formName, requestID, fieldIds);

//add the attachment
AttachmentValue attachment = new AttachmentValue("name_of_file.ext", "path/to/file.ext");
entry.put(550000011, new Value(attachment));
arsConnection.setEntry(formName, newEntry,null,0);
```

to do this, you need the request id. this code is using the java API.